# What is the power of Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

I have just started to watch the Naruto Shippuden series. I saw the fight of Pain, but I can't understand the power of Rinnegan. Can anyone explain the power of Rinnegan?

Comment: Explaining to you the powers of Rinnegan might contain spoilers.=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend that you wait until the anime explains it all.

Anyway, ***spoiler alert!***

Well it's not just one power, it's a set of powers combined together.

1. Master all five basic nature transformations and the capacity to use any technique.
2. The Rinnegan allows the user to see chakra.
3. Rinnegan's field of vision can be multiple due to animated body's or summons.
4. Grants the ability to summon and control the Demonic Statue of the Outer Path.
5. Creating corporeal shadows which are only visible to the Rinnegan.
6. Shift spaces within a certain range.
7. Control over life and death.
8. Transmit their chakra to black receivers as well as manifest the chakra chains (to control Tailed Beast or use a dead body as a host).
9. Planet creation.
10. Six Paths Technique.

Six Paths Technique can be divided into 6 (just like its name lol :) )

1. Deva Path—can be used to attract and repel targets.
2. Asura Path—can clad the user in mechanised armour and grant them various weapons.
3. Human Path—can read minds, at the cost of ripping out the victim's soul.
4. Animal Path—can summon various creatures.
5. Preta Path—can absorb any chakra-based ninjutsu and even from a person's body.
6. Naraka Path—can summon the King of Hell, which can be used for interrogation and restoration.

Answer is based on Anime & Manga and the naruto.wikia.com.
For more info, see [naruto.wikia.com](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan).